# Change backend service based on GraphQL Param

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I have a GraphQL Schema as such:

```
BigParent (parentParam: Boolean) {
  id
  name
  Parent {
    id
    name
    Child (childParam: Boolean) {
      id
      name
    }
  }
}
```

How can I write resolvers such that I call different backend APIs based on whether the `parentParam` is `true` or the `childParam` is `true`? The first option is straight-forward. The second one needs to kind of reconstruct the Graph based on the values returned by the service data returned at the level of `Child`.

I'm not considering both the options as true, as I'll assign some priority so that the param at child level is not considered while the param at the parent level is passed.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the arguments for any field selection in the query by traversing the GraphQL resolver `info` parameter.

Assuming your query looks like this:

```
query {
  BigParent(parentParam: Boolean) {
    id
    name
    Parent {
      id
      name
      Child(childParam: Boolean) {
        id
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You should be able to do something like this:

```
function getChildParam(info) {
  // TODO: Return 'childParam'
}

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    async BigParent(parent, args, context, info) {
      // 'args' contains the 'parentParam' argument
      const parentParam = args.parentParam;

      // Extract the 'childParam' argument from the info object
      const childParam = getChildParam(info);

      if (parentParam || childParam) {
        return context.datasource1.getData();
      }

      return context.datasource2.getData();
    },
  },
};
```